# Thread not working in Storm Cluster

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, apache-storm

I'm trying to do the following, Start stream listener in a separate thread that will create a queues, Than those queue will be processed later on... however `Storm` doesn't do anything after thread. It stuck over there.

And my code looks like this:

```
import os, sys, traceback, random, StringIO, time
import random
from uuid import uuid4
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import pyinotify
import simplejson, pycurl
import sys, signal
import twitter
import tweepy
import Queue
import threading
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

import storm
queue = Queue.Queue()

class MyModelParser(tweepy.parsers.ModelParser):
    def parse(self, method, payload):
        result = super(MyModelParser, self).parse(method, payload)
        result._payload = json.loads(payload)
        return result

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    ''' Handles data received from the stream. '''
    def __init__(self, api, q):
        self.api = api
        self.queue = q
        self.queue.put('lalala')

    def on_status(self, status):
        self.queue.put('%s' % status.author.screen_name)
        self.queue.task_done()

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return True # To continue listening

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # To continue listening

class Starter():
    def __init__(self,q):
        self.queue = q
        hashtag = ['justinbieber','snooki','daddy_yankee','MikeTyson','iamdiddy','lala']
        auth = self.t_auth()
        api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=MyModelParser())
        stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth,CustomStreamListener(api,queue))
        stream.filter(follow=None, track=hashtag)

    def t_auth(self):
        consumer_key=""
        consumer_secret=""
        access_key = ""
        access_secret = ""

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret) 

        return auth 

class TwitterSpout(storm.Spout):
    SPOUT_NAME = "TwitterSpout"
    queue = queue

    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        self.pid = os.getpid()      
        try:
            t = threading.Thread(target=Starter(self.queue) )
            t.daemon=True
            t.start()           

        except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
            self.log('\n\nStopping')
            raise
```

Comment: don't know so much python. still asking, if you simply try to push in queues, and later process from there, is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Use pyleus(https://github.com/Yelp/pyleus) and your spout implementation should have next_tuple(self): which should emit the output fields as in the example below;

```
from pyleus.storm import Spout


class DummySpout(Spout):

    OUTPUT_FIELDS = ['sentence', 'name']

    def initialize(self):
        pass

    def next_tuple(self):
        self.emit(("This is a sentence.", "spout",))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DummySpout().run()
```

then write your bolt;

```
from pyleus.storm import SimpleBolt


class DummyBolt(SimpleBolt):

OUTPUT_FIELDS = ['sentence']

def process_tuple(self, tup):
    sentence, name = tup.values
    new_sentence = "{0} says, \"{1}\"".format(name, sentence)
    self.emit((new_sentence,), anchors=[tup])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DummyBolt().run()
```

you can also have a look at how i am using it;
https://github.com/Yelp/pyleus/issues/140